# postfix smtp server initial server greeting error

Tags: postfix

I've installed postfix in centos and attempted to send an email but I get the error
'Lost connection while receiving the initial server greeting'. The error occurs with gmail, hotmail and my work email domain. The VM where postfix is running is placed behind a firewall with outbound internet connection. I've googled the error message and most of the results point to

- domain being blacklisted
- lack of ssl
- local firewall

I've just configured a local domain in the /etc/hosts file of the vm where postfix is running - privateip hostname.somedomain.com. Could this be the issue?
Is SSL mandatory?
Or am I completely wrong in the configuration?

Comment: What happens when you use other tools to connect to one of those domains' SMTP MX servers? For example, (based on information shown by `host -t mx gmail.com`), what happens when you use `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`? Do you get the "220 <name> ESMTP" greeting line?

Comment: I'm able to telnet to the gmail server on port 25 but I don't see a greeting

Trying 74.125.200.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Can you do the same on the firewall? It is either a firewall problem or an ISP problem.

Comment: I checked the firewall logs and I see the firewall rules allow the traffic. I suspect I'm not meeting the pre-requisites of gmail or any other domains. Is SSL mandatory?

Comment: No. Additionally, Postfix's connection and your test are stopping _before_ TLS can begin to be negotiated.